# Iterate over XML element and push element into array

Tags: php, xml, iterator

I have a simple XML document containing two city id's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<config>
    <city>
        <id>London</id>
    </city>
    <city>
        <id>New York</id>
    </city>
</config>
```

When iterating over the XML I can only pick up the first city id, e.g. London.

```
<?php
$configFile = 'cityConfig.xml';

function getCityId($configFile) {

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents("cityConfig.xml"));

    $cities = array();

    foreach ($xml->city->id as $cityId) {
        $cityId = (string) $cityId;
        array_push($cities, $cityId);
    }

    return $cities;
}

print_r(getCityId($configFile));
?>

<?php
```

The output from the above:

```
// Array ( [0] => London )
```

I'm casting `$cityId` into a string to be used elsewhere in my website.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you should iterate over `$xml->city as $city`, then use `$city->id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->city->id as $cityId)
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($xml->city as $city) {
    $cityId = $city->id;
    ...
}
```